# How to trim an specific string in IOS?

Tags: ios7, nsstring

I have a string that I like to trim the first and last character. What is the equivalent of ltrim/rtrim in IOS?

This is the string:

```
"["email@email.com","email@email.com"]"
```

I want to remove only the first and last double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[substringWithRange](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/substringWithRange:):

```
string = [string substringWithRange:(NSRange){1, str.length - 2}];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str = @"    sample string   ";
NSString *trimmedString = [str stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```